# Is ADD AX, DATA8 the Same with ADD AL, DATA8 in 8086 Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, x86

In my question:

AX= 16 bit accumulator register.

AL= 8 low meaning bits of  AX register.
DATA8= Immediate number which can be most 8 bit. In base ten, it can be between 0-255 If this number is unsignificant. We assume this number is unsign.

DATA16= One hexadecimal number which comprise of 16bits.

So, back to the question:

In 8086 Instructor set, `ADD AX, DATA16` takes 4 clock cycles long and it's object code is **05 YYYY**.

In **05 YYYY** , 05 is 1 byte and YY is also one byte so entire of this object code is 3 byte size. `ADD AL, DATA8` takes 4 clock cyle like `ADD AX,DATA16` but `ADD AX, DATA8`'s object code is **04 YY**

If I write `ADD AX, 10H`  , my source operand(operand 2) is hexadecimal 10 so it is 8 bit. AX comprise of AH and AL. AH is 8 bits of most significant bits of AX and AL is opposite 8 bits. But in our code `ADD AX, 10H` ,  we add AX with 8 bit number and update AX. According the AX consists AH and AL, Actually, we are doing summation with AL and 10H in this code, so will our code's size be 2 byte regarding of **04 YY** or in compliance with 8086 Instruction Set, Do we obey the rule strict and don't think like these and we accept in **AX, DATA8**, our first operand is AX but 2nd operand is DATA8 and Insturction set doesn't have mnemonic like this, so we think it must be **AL, DATA8**?

Forgive me, I draged out this question too much.

Comment: No, it's not the same because you may get carry from AL to AH. If your assembler generates opcode `04` for `add ax, imm` then it's broken.

Comment: I know it, but I ask their size according to instruction set. Inst. set hasn't  AX, DATA8 because AX is 2 bytes. But what will be this AX, 10h code's size?  2 bytes or 3 bytes?

Comment: To encode `add ax, 2`, you'd use the `add r/m16, imm8` encoding with the ModRM byte encoding the AX destination.  Or `add ax, imm8` if you want; for AX they're the same size: 3 bytes total.  (For EAX in 32-bit mode, `add r/m32, imm8` is still 3 bytes, `add eax, imm32` is 5 bytes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `ADD AX, imm` instruction, opcode `05h`, the immediate is always encoded as two bytes (16 bits), even if it happens to be less than 255.  Your `ADD AX, 10h` is encoded as `05 10 00`, three bytes.

This is the only way it can work.  The CPU just sees bytes; it would have no way of knowing whether `10` represents a one-byte immediate and the next byte is part of the next instruction, or whether `10` is the low byte of a two-byte operand.  In other words, how is it to know whether `05 10 90` is `ADD AX, 10h ; NOP` or `ADD AX, 9010h`?  The only way to resolve this is to declare that opcode 05 *always* takes a two-byte immediate, and if the desired value fits in one byte, then the most significant byte is simply specified as zero.

Note there is another form of `ADD`, opcode `83h`, which takes a one-byte (8-bit) immediate and sign-extends it to 16 bits.  Since your immediate `10h` does fit in a signed 8-bit number, this form could be used.  However, since its destination is a general r/m operand, it needs an extra byte to specify the register, and would encode as `83 c0 10`, still three bytes.  Note this would not work if you wanted to add the unsigned 8-bit quantity `a0h`, as it would be sign-extended to `ffa0h`.

`ADD AL, 10h` is encoded as two bytes `04 10` as you say, but as Jester notes it is not the same as `ADD AX, 10h` because you can have a carry from the low to high bytes.  If `AX` contains `00f3h`, then `ADD AX, 10h` will result in `AX = 0103h` and the carry flag clear, while `ADD AL, 10h` will result in `AX = 0003h` and the carry flag set.